# 5x5 grid with a special colouring

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics

Can you paint the cells of a 5x5 grid in 5 colours such that for each cell its colour and the colour of its orthogonal (horizontal and vertical) neighbours are all different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Someone](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/122940/77182) had the right idea:

> ```
> abcde
> cdeab
> eabcd
> bcdea
> deabc
> ```

Now in Technicolor, so you can see it for yourself:

> [image: a 5x5 grid matching the pattern in the first spoiler block]

Comment: And the same applies for the diagonal neighbours independently. *And* the edges "wrap".

Comment: This is correct, well done! Love the technicolor :)

Comment: I wonder why, mathematically, rot13(ebgngvat nopqr ol gjb naq guerr) yield valid solutions. Does it have anything to do with rot13(zbqhyne nevguzrgvp)?

Comment: @Someone I think it's more that they're effectively mirrors of the same operation. if you were to flip the board over horizontally and relabel the colors I'm pretty sure one would come out as the other

Comment: Yeah, they're interchangeable, and reflections of each other. But I'm having trouble finding a non-trivial non-bonus solution.

Comment: There is only one solution, up to reflection and permutation of the colors.

Answer (score 3):

## Trivial Solution (similar to others')

And of course, it also grabs the bonus:

> Let a, b, c, d, e be the colors. Then:
>  | a | b | c | d | e |
>  | d | e | a | b | c |
>  | b | c | d | e | a |
>  | e | a | b | c | d |
>  | c | d | e | a | b |

How I got there:

> If you take `abcde`, place it in the first row, and then right-shift it by three for each row, you get this system.

Comment: Oh, I misread the question. Might as well look for another solution…

Comment: I made it more readable but unfortunately [tables don't work in spoilers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/357005/579077).

Comment: Alright, actual solution now.

Comment: Is this the same solution as the accepted one? Are there any other solutions (perhaps without the bonus)?

Comment: They're not the same, but they have a similar idea to each other and my first solution—rot13(gnxr n ebj bs gur svir pbybef naq fuvsg gurz nebhaq).

Comment: It's essentially the same, with the rows going in the other direction.

Comment: That's the math behind the trivial bonus solutions. I'm curious to see how one could find a non-bonus one…

Comment: There is only one solution, up to reflection and permutation of the colors.

Comment: I wasn't able to find any other solutions.

Comment: Maybe a proof is in order?

Answer (score 0):

Initially I assumed this was a Latin square question (but that was not actually mentioned).  I got the following symmetrical solution:

> [image: Rainbowish colored 5x5 matrix]

Comment: This doesn't work, sorry. It wasn't a latin square question, but it turned into one :)

Comment: That was my original solution, but I misread the question.

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky Well this is disappointing.  I have received two downvotes for my answer even though none of my colored squares have a horizontal or vertical neighbour of the same color.  Plus I did use 5 colors as requested.  I feel I have correctly answered the question that was asked.

Comment: Not my DV but your black squares have 4 orthogonal neighbours of all the same colour, while the question asks "orthogonal (horizontal and vertical) neighbours are all different"

Comment: If you look at, for example, the top-left square, two of its neighbors have the same color. This is the same misreading I did.

Comment: @WeatherVane Okay!  I see the difference now.  I had interpreted the question to only mean that each cell would be colored different from its orthogonal neighbours but now I see that also the 4 orthogonal neighbours must all be distinctly colored.

Comment: @Someone I see we misinterpreted the question the same way.

Comment: @WillOctagonGibson yep just a misinterpretation. Probably my question was poorly written. I gave you a +1 so you don't feel so bad :)

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky Thanks!  Sometimes it’s hard to word things simply and clearly.  I thought about how I would word your question and I couldn’t think of a simple way to express it.